# Power Automate: How can I void the DocuSign envelope using Custom Connectors with a dynamic envelope id?

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate

I would like to create a custom connector into Power Automate to void the DocuSign envelope (contract).

But the issue is I don't want to pass the envelope id as in URL this envelope id will be dynamic/parameter.

I know, we can pass this url

```
https://{{environment}}.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{AccountID}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}
```

but here `envelopeId` will be fixed, I want to send as dynamic or as parameterized one or any random one.

Please help how can I use a dynamic envelope ID not fixed one.

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really a Power Automate question, so I added the `Power-Automate` tag. I just did a quick google search and found this [solution for a dynamic URL by using braces](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/How-to-pass-arguments-to-a-custom-connector/m-p/214017/highlight/true#M5476) for the variable in the URL path. See the screenshot below.

If that doesn't work, and there is no way to use a dynamic URL path value as the envelope ID, then you will need to create your own API and API server.

Your server would receive the envelope ID as a parameter in the request body, and then make the appropriate API call to DocuSign.

DocuSign's use of variables in the URL path is standard REST. So I'd be very surprised if Power Automate still does not support this API pattern. (But you may need to update to the latest Power Automate version.)

[image: Solution from Power-Automate forum]

Comment: Thank you, it is working. your are genius!!!